# How to generate new page in zend PDF in foreach loop

Tags: loops, pdf, zend-framework

please explain how can generate new pages in pdf for foreach loop content

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$items = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $page->setFont($font, 9)
         ->setFillColor(Zend_Pdf_Color_Html::color('#000000'))
         ->drawText('Text 1', 0, 800);
}
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
$pdf->save('wishlist.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code to add new blank pages in your pdf file.

```
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
```

and than assign to

```
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
```